# After Upgrading to Spring Boot 1.5, Apache commons fileupload FileItemIterator has no elements

Tags: spring-boot, apache-commons-fileupload

After upgrading to Spring Boot 1.5.2 from 1.3.8, our streaming fileupload no longer works.

Here is the setup.

1. include commons-fileupload:1.3.1
2. disable the embedded tomcat fileupload by specifying this in application.yml

**multipart.enabled: false**

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemIterator;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
...
@RequestMapping(
    value = '/upload ,
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
 )
 public ResponseEntity<MyObject> uploadFile(HttpServletRequest request) {
     ResponseEntity<MyObject> retval = null;
     boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
     if (isMultipart) {
         ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload();
         FileItemIterator iter = upload.getItemIterator(request); <<< 
         // iter contains no elements when using SpringBoot 1.5.2 
         // iter does contain the expected elements when using SpingBoot 1.4.+
         // I tried commons-fileupload:1.3.1 and 1.3.3
         while (iter.hasNext()) { <<< no elements when using Spring boot 1.5
             ...
         }
         ...
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring Boot version 1.4, the multipart namespace was changed to [spring.http.multipart](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes). To disable the Spring Boot StandardServletMultipartResolver which also disables the embedded tomcat fileupload that writes to disk, the new environment property needs to be set instead.

I do this in application.yml

**spring.http.multipart.enabled: false**

This allows commons-fileupload streaming w/o writing to disk to work again in my environment.